# Tensorflow/Keras GPU low usage: Jupyter Notebook seems to be training on CPU instead of GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook, gpu

I am training a series of models from https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-with-python-notebooks/blob/master/5.1-introduction-to-convnets.ipynb on my local device, which should be correctly set up and more than capable to run these is record times but instead it seems to be quite slow and seems to be using CPU.

Local setup:

Hardware:

- GeForce RTX 2070 Super, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability:
  7.5
- CPU: i9-10980HK@2.4GHz

Software:

- Windows 10 Pro
- Cuda_11.2.r11.2
- Python 3.8.8
- Tensorflow: 2.4.1
- Keras: 2.4.3

Jupyter Notebook checks:

- device_lib.list_local_devices(): "physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: GeForce RTX 2070 Super, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5"
- When training a a network in logs we have: "tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties:pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 2070 Super computeCapability: 7.5
  coreClock: 1.38GHz coreCount: 40 deviceMemorySize: 8.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 417.29GiB/s"

So everything seems pretty correctly set up, except one warning that I do get: "Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set"

But, the thing that makes me question everything is that when I start training only the CPU activity seems to be increasing to around 25% while the **GPU remains unchanged**.

Now, I am aware that this might be too light for the processing power available (which is quite a lot) and it might not be breaking any sweat.
If true, then the next question comes in, why is training taking a similar time to original training times that can be found in the source code, which is at least 3 years old and definitely trained on much much lower resources.

And there would be another potential question, maybe worthy of a different thread: How could we parallelize training the tf/keras models on faster GPU devices, is such a shame to have a capable device but not being able to harness it's entire processing power.

P.S: I do have 15+ years experience in software dev and and dev ops and a little familiar with ML so I think I did run all the possible checks and do have a decent picture on how the components interact, but it feels like I am missing something in here, so please share any insight as technical as it can get.

Comment: I think you have to manually configure keras to run on GPU otherwise it falls back to CPU

Comment: e.g. # Process the first sequence on one GPU
with tf.device_scope('/gpu:0'):
    encoded_a = shared_lstm(input_a) from here https://keras.io/getting_started/faq/

Comment: @Octav that is to use multiple GPUs, single GPUs are automatically used if available.

Comment: You cannot determine if GPU is being used by looking at utilization, the network here is very small and so is the dataset, so you could be using close to 0% of the GPU power.

Comment: Thanks @Octav, but I do have only one GPU, still I think I might have reached something here and in a subsequent test 5.3-using-a-pretrained-convnet.ipynb the Dedicated GPU Memory has increased to 6.5GB and the epoch training time has decreased from original code 75s to 12s (GPU still low so probably is doing the processing slowly). So it is using the GPU by the looks of it but the last question stands, how could we optimize/parallelize/accelerate training on capable devices?

Comment: Thanks @Dr.Snoopy, it does make sense. Any recommendations on a test/benchmark (tensorflow/keras training I mean) that uses the GPU/CPUs to it's full potential?

Comment: Train a ResNet20 on CIFAR10, that requires considerable more GPU power.